# App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs) a method suitable for redefinition was not found

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have created a new project.
The UWP project contains errors.

**Error:**

- "App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)": No method suitable for overriding was found. // **Xamarin.Forms.App1.UWP**.
- the "CompileXaml" task returned false, but did not register an error. **Xamarin.Forms.App1.UWP**.
- Shared "App" declarations should not specify different base classes. **Xamarin.Forms.App1.UWP**.

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

---

## Update-1

---

**I use:**

- Visual Studio Community 2019. Version 16.11.20.

**I have installed:**

- JetBrains ReSharper.

---

**Composition of the solution:**
**Xamarin.Forms.App1 (netstandard2.0):**

- Xamarin.Forms-Version="5.0.0.2012"
- Xamarin.Essentials-Version="1.6.1"

**Xamarin.Forms.App1.Android()**

- Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2012"
- Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1"

**Xamarin.Forms.App1.UWP**

- Xamarin.Forms Version="5.0.0.2012"
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform - Version="6.2.12"
- Xamarin.Essentials Version="1.6.1"

---

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Xamarin.Forms.App1.UWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Picture - **App.xaml.cs** (I attach a picture of the code so that the distribution of errors can be seen)
[image]

---

## **Update-2**

**1.**

> Did you try to clean the project and rebuild it?

I cleaned up the project and rebuilt it.
This did not solve the problem.

**2.**

> And is there any similar error in the android or the ios part?

I don't see any problems with `android` and `ios`.

**Picture-5**
[image]

**3.** [Download Project](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/LtoOOR1z4ut-ng)

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and rebuild it? And is there any similar error in the android or the ios part?

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT See `Update-2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is your project name. The `Application` in the  `sealed partial class App : Application` is herited from the `Xamarin.Forms`.

So you can just created a new project and name it `App1` instead of `Xamarin.Forms.App1`, the project will have no error.

Or just change the code in your project such as:

```
sealed partial class App : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application

Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Windows.UI.Xaml.ControlsFrame;

rootFrame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
```